# Get C Code Stack Trace in Go Program

Tags: go

I'm using the [rana/ora](https://github.com/rana/ora) oracle driver in my Go program to query some Oracle tables.

The program somehow always gets SIGSEGV from a C library after running for a while and exits on segfault. It also gets a lot of query timeouts (`context deadline exceeded`) before it hits segfault error.

I'm using the driver in a pretty standard way:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Seconds)
defer cancel()
rows, err := initialedDb.QueryContext(ctx, "sql_query")
```

The stack trace from the 1st Goroutine is:

```
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x70 pc=0x7fbb03e5d193]
runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0xa4a0a4, 0x2a)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:596 +0x95
runtime.sigpanic()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:274 +0x2db
goroutine 5230 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.cgocall(0x921850, 0xc421667348, 0xa495f1)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:131 +0xe2 fp=0xc421667308 sp=0xc4216672c8
gopkg.in/rana/ora%2ev4._Cfunc_OCIAttrGet(0x2c92f08, 0x35, 0xc421cb8be4, 0xc421cb8be8, 0x5, 0x2b81930, 0xc400000000)
    gopkg.in/rana/ora.v4/_obj/_cgo_gotypes.go:347 +0x4d fp=0xc421667348 sp=0xc421667308
gopkg.in/rana/ora%2ev4.(*Rset).paramAttr.func1(0x2c92f08, 0xc400000035, 0xc421cb8be4, 0xc421cb8be8, 0x5, 0x2b81930, 0xf1ef01)
    /go/src/gopkg.in/rana/ora.v4/rset.go:970 +0xfc fp=0xc421667390 sp=0xc421667348
gopkg.in/rana/ora%2ev4.(*Rset).paramAttr(0xc4211f22d0, 0x2c92f08, 0xc421cb8be4, 0xc421cb8be8, 0xc400000005, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/gopkg.in/rana/ora.v4/rset.go:976 +0x88 fp=0xc4216673e0 sp=0xc421667390
gopkg.in/rana/ora%2ev4.(*Rset).open(0xc4211f22d0, 0xc421358000, 0x7fbae405ed28, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/gopkg.in/rana/ora.v4/rset.go:554 +0xd43 fp=0xc421667b98 sp=0xc4216673e0
gopkg.in/rana/ora%2ev4.(*Stmt).qryC(0xc421358000, 0xf1e940, 0xc421ace900, 0xc421cb8ad0, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc4211f22d0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/gopkg.in/rana/ora.v4/stmt.go:442 +0x3e0 fp=0xc421667f18 sp=0xc421667b98
gopkg.in/rana/ora%2ev4.(*DrvStmt).QueryContext.func1(0xc421b73260, 0xc420e789e8, 0xc420e789e0, 0xf1e940, 0xc421ace900, 0xc421cb8ad0, 0x1, 0x1)
    /go/src/gopkg.in/rana/ora.v4/drvStmt_go1_8.go:76 +0xa6 fp=0xc421667fa0 sp=0xc421667f18
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2197 +0x1 fp=0xc421667fa8 sp=0xc421667fa0
created by gopkg.in/rana/ora%2ev4.(*DrvStmt).QueryContext
    /go/src/gopkg.in/rana/ora.v4/drvStmt_go1_8.go:82 +0x30c
```

I checked my program many times and I don't think I'm causing any memory leaks, double frees or anything like that.

I wonder how I can debug this since Go doesn't give me C's stack trace. Will Valgrind's Memcheck tool help?

Comment: I wonder if you might be experiencing [issue 20160](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20160) fixed recently [commit](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/2133d63fa81777315981fbf961338218832e5099). Also, does the full stack trace suggest the garbage collector might be involved?

Comment: @Mark I think it's highly possible. Will take a look

Comment: @Mark It looks like a fix to my issue.  Do you know how often they merge master into 1.8 release branch?

Comment: @JFreebird: master doesn't get merged into old release branches, it's the next release. You can easily build Go from source and see if it fixes your issue.  Also make sure you've pulled the latest commits from the ora.v4 package. Also make sure you're _not_ using `GODEBUG=cgocheck=0` as these errors could be caused by incorrect use of Go pointers in cgo.

Comment: The thing is I'm running it in Docker.  And I'm just using Go's official docker image. My local doesn't have the environment to compile the program. I think it's not straightforward to build Go into a docker image myself.